# Profile Image displaying on Wrong side of Wordpress Navigation Menu

Tags: images, menus, hooks

Am creating a WordPress site whereby am enabling users to upload their own custom profile images from a custom form. Once they upload am storing the image URL in a database table and the image is then stored inside the WordPress wp-content/uploads folder. This works fine.

When a user logs in, I want to display the profile photo next to the username at the top-left corner of the dashboard.

To achieve this I have utilized the init action hook that fetches the image URL from the database and stores it in a wp_cache.

```
function fectch_custom_profile_picture() {


    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {

        global $wpdb;
        $user_id = get_current_user_id(); 
        $table_name  = "profile_details";
    
    //Query table to fetch image Url
        $query_result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM  $table_name WHERE user_id =  $user_id");
    
    //Store image url in cache
        wp_cache_set( 'profileImageUrl', $query_result[0]->avatarUrl);
    } 
}
add_action( 'init', 'fectch_custom_profile_picture' );
```

Next, am utilizing nav_menu_item_title to append the photo next to username, this shoudl be displayed instantly. Ideally it should be: **Welcome test [profileimagehere]**

```
function add_image_beside_username($title, $menu_item , $args, $depth) {
    
    //Fetch the image from wp_cache and store in a variable
    $img = '<img src="' . wp_cache_get( 'profileImageUrl' ) .'" class="custom-avatar">';
     
    //Ultimate Member logged in details
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    um_fetch_user( $user_id );
    $display_name = um_user('display_name');

     //Check if title is equal to: Welcome {username}, if true appand the profile image next to it
    if($title == 'Welcome ' .  $display_name){
        $title .=  print_r($img);
     }
     return $title;
}
add_filter('nav_menu_item_title', 'add_image_beside_username', 10, 4);
```

The image displays on the screen but it displays on the wrong side. See below.

[image]

I want it to display on the far-left corner after **Welcome test**.

Researched this for hours but not successful, Please assist?

Comment: You shouldn’t be using `print_r()`.

Comment: @JacobPeattie I ahve tries using echo like this `$title .= 'echo&lt;img src="'.wp_cache_get( 'profileImageUrl' ).'" alt="image-icon"&gt;';` but insead of the image displaying it prints the html:  **Welcome testecho<img src="http://wplocaltheme.test/wp-content/themes/careersnapshot/assets/images/profile-image-14.svg" alt="image-icon">**  .. Please assist in editing the code,

Comment: @JacobPeattie  Please bear with me,, am very new to wordpress hooks, your assistance will be of great importance.

Comment: You shouldn’t be echoing or printing $img at all. Just concatenate it to $title and you should be fine.

Comment: "After Welcome Test" is not `far-left`. It is `far-right`

Comment: @JacobPeattie Okay thanks a lot, I appreciate..